# key events are working on emulator but not on mobile

Tags: android

my key events are working on emulator but when i installed my app my phone is unable to recognize its key event. help me on this
I am using View.onKey event listener.
My code is:-
case 1: e1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

```
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Respective_Swashes_Slanted.ttf"); 
              if(arg2.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
              {

                  e2.setTypeface(type);
                  e2.setTextSize(30);
                  e2.setText(e1.getText()); 
              }
            return false;
        }
    });



        break;
    case 2: e1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/doridrobot.ttf"); 
              if(arg2.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
              {

                  e2.setTypeface(type);
                  e2.setTextSize(30);
                  e2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                  e2.setText(e1.getText()); 
              }
            return false;
        }
    });

        break;
```

case 3: e1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

```
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/future.ttf"); 
              if(arg2.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
              {

                  e2.setTypeface(type);
                  e2.setTextSize(30);
                  e2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                  e2.setText(e1.getText()); 
              }
            return false;
        }
    });

        break;
```

case 4: e1.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/flattered.ttf"); 
      if(arg2.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
      {

          e2.setTypeface(type);
          e2.setTextSize(30);
          e2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
          e2.setText(e1.getText()); 
      }
    return false;
}
```

});

```
break;

    }

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: do i need to use ontouch event?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html):

> Called when a hardware key is dispatched to a view. This allows
>   listeners to get a chance to respond before the target view.
>
> Key presses in software keyboards will generally NOT trigger this
>   method, although some may elect to do so in some situations. Do not
>   assume a software input method has to be key-based; even if it is, it
>   may use key presses in a different way than you expect, so there is no
>   way to reliably catch soft input key presses.

So basically if your device doesn't have a hardware keyboard then the `onKey` may not fire.
Depending on your requirement you can use

[onTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) - invoked at any touch event

[onClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) -  invoked when a view is clicked.

Or any of the other [listeners](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html) that android provides.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a reliable way to detect keyboard presses in onTouch event, since it works on any view.  If you are working with a text field than you might want to use a [textWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html). Normally when the keyboard is up, the user is editing some kind of text field.  The text watcher will let you know each time something changes in that text box.